# How to get Arduino/ESP32 device details in code?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I'm working on a project in which there is a server and several clients (ESP32). In short, It's client-server communication over WIFI. Right now, I'm using ESP32-wroom-32D. In future, for a client device, I might use some other Arduino device or other ESP32 module or a combination of both. For code simplicity, I shall be using the same code for both types of devices (Arduino/ ESP32) as they support a common Arduino platform. Therefore, I want to know if there is a way which I can get the device's information.

Eg.
Function: Get_device_details( ) or Get_device_id( ).

Output: "ESP32-Wroom-32D" or "Arduino Mega 2560"

Comment: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1694

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino defines to identify a board are in form of `ARDUINO_<board>`, where `<board>` is the value from `<x>.build.board` from boards.txt for board `<x>`

For example for Arduino AVR boards, in the boards.txt file is `uno.build.board=AVR_UNO` so the define is `ARDUINO_AVR_UNO`.

And Arduino has ['architecture' identification define](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#working-with-multiple-architectures) too. This has form of `ARDUINO_ARCH_<arch.name>`. The `<arch.name>` is the uppercase version of the folder name with the boards package version. For example AVR for packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21.

Answer (score 1):

For esp boards, you can use the following arduino code to get chip ID,

```
#ifdef ESP8266
int chip_id = ESP.getChipId();
#elif defined(ESP32)
int chip_id = ESP.getEfuseMac();
#endif
```

Comment: This is actually a bit useful. Thanks